# Image not aligning center in div when using @media

Tags: html, css

I have a @media where I adjust how the images look on my site to then layout side by side. Instead of stacking one above the other. I have gotten the images to the stack side by side, but cause of the previous display settings from other divs I am struggling to get my images center aligned when at a min px width of 1600.

My live site is http://factormedia.co.za/contact.html

As you can see they stack side by side, but wont center align. I am not that great with the display settings, so it has confused me as to why it wont center.

This is the CSS in question

```
/*---------------------------- Scaling ----------------------------*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px){
    .intouch {
        margin-top:15%;
    }
    .contact{
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        padding:0 3% 0 3%;
    }
    .contactwrap1 {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .contactwrap1 img{
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jox0vg0L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this a little easier to calculate start by changing `.contact`

**from** `.contact{padding: 0 3% 0 3%;}`

**to** `.contact{padding: 0 40px 0 40px;}`

This will make each `.contact` a total of 230px a piece.

Multiple by number of `.contact` (4) and you get `760px`

on your wrapper `.detailwrap` add this:

`.detailwrap{padding-left: calc((100% - 760px) / 2)}`

This will center your icons :)

Comment: wow didnt even know you could use a calc to make padding. Thanks man that was a simple fix! Really have to learn this stuff D:

Comment: I did notice one problem, by doing that it pushes my width of my entire page out as well

Comment: Without having a fiddle to play with, I can only get you close by using inspect element on your page. If you upload your page to a fiddle, I can get it to work better, if not did you stick it in your media query?

Comment: I have now added a fiddle

Comment: I forgot to make the width of the div smaller see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jox0vg0L/1/

Comment: awesome thanks man :) what are you calculating specifically there?

Comment: The offset of the padding, if you for instance have a block the is set to `100px` wide and add `50px` of padding the total width is now `150px`. that is what happened, I added the width to the fiddle to compensate for the added padding.

Comment: In the fiddle it works till about 1800 I still have some overflow, but making it 740 seems to fix this problem

Comment: My day is done at work, if you have anymore questions, I can answer them tomorrow, goodluck!